# want to use PHP Null coalescing operator (??) with comperison

Tags: php, laravel

if I just want results based on `var` value set or not? so that I can simply use this

`$lab_type=$label['type']??null;`

but if want to compare `$label['type']` response with using `??` operator, then how to do.

want to change it

```
 <option value="background" <?= isset($label['type'])?$label['type']=='background'?'selected':'':'selected'?> >Background</option>
```

don't want to use `isset` here.

Comment: what are you looking to do exactly . it seems not clair .

Comment: Use `$label['type']??''` first to either get the value, or an empty string - and then proceed to compare that with `'background'` …?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your ternary operator to:

```
<?= ($label['type'] ?? null) == 'background' ? 'selected' : '' ?>
```